# specific amount of loop in python

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to create a code in python where user has to enter how many inputs there will be in a loop.I want to implement it with this code:

```
i = int(input(''))
  if int(i) in range (50 , 61):
    print('5')
  if int(i) in range (40 , 50):
    print('4')
  if int(i) in range (30 , 40):
    print('3')
  if int(i) in range (0 , 30):
    print('U')
```

the above only runs once and I want to create a loop where I first have to input how many times it should run i.e "3" times or "5" times. I tried to use while-loop but failed

Comment: you don;t need to cast i to int every time. you already did that in the input.

Comment: Post the while loop so we can see what went wrong.

Comment: So if a user enter 3, the program will then ask him 3 times for three numbers ?

Comment: @Aymen correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running code a certain number of times, `for` usually works better than `while`.

```
count = int(input("Enter number of loops: "))
for _ in range(count):
    i = int(input(''))
    if int(i) in range (50 , 61):
        print('5')
    if int(i) in range (40 , 50):
        print('4')
    if int(i) in range (30 , 40):
        print('3')
    if int(i) in range (0 , 30):
        print('U')
```

And while we're at it, we can clean up that wall of `if`s. You can pull your ranges into a list and loop through that instead.

```
my_ranges = [ (range(50, 61), '5'), (range(40, 50), '4'), (range(30,40), '3'),
    (range(0, 30), 'U')]
    
count = int(input("Enter number of loops: "))
for _ in range(count):
    i = int(input(''))
    for r, val in my_ranges:
        if i in r:
            print(val)
            break
```

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki - good point. OP doesn't have an else condition so there isn't one here, but for future readers, and `else` at the end of the `for` would run if there was not a break.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki -what are you talking about? There is no need for for a binary search on this code. Why would we add that sort of complication for a beginning coder?